# Cambiar un Campo de NULL a NOT NULL en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy estructurando una BD en SQL Server 2017 y tenía una duda de si podía hacer lo siguiente en este caso:

Tengo 4 Tablas:

`Maestro`, `DetalleMaestro`, `Seccion`, `SubSeccion`.

La estructura es esta:

```
Maestro
    id
  , Nombre
  , Apellido

DetalleMaestro
    id
  , idMaestro
  , idSeccion
  , idSubSeccion <-- este ultimo campo es NOT NULL .

Seccion
    id
  , Seccion

SubSeccion 
    id
  , SubSeccion
```

### La pregunta es la siguiente:

> Existen dos tipos de secciones: una tiene mas subsecciones –a esta la
>   llamaremos A– y la otra no –a esta le llamaremos B–

Si tengo un maestro y este es asignado a la sección B que no tiene subsecciones,

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el campo 'SubSeccion' sea NULL solamente para ese maestro en específico?

¿Es posible alterar el tipo del valor de un campo solo para un registro?

Comment: Y por que no lo piensas distinto: no podrías tener una `SubSeccion` que sea `Sin subsección` y asignarle este dato?

Comment: Siento decirte que la propiedad NULL no se puede asociar a relaciones con otras tablas, lo tendrás que hacer por CHECK o bien por TRIGGERS.